# having another issue with mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query...

```
SELECT c.idx, c.club_name, s.sale_event_date, s.club_id, COUNT(*) AS total_guests, 
sum(s.qr_scanned = 1) AS total_scanned_guests, 
SUM(s.rep_sale_commission ON (s.rep_id != 0 AND s.qr_scanned = 1)) AS total_rep_commission, 
 SUM(s.sale_commission) AS total_admin_fees
FROM club c RIGHT JOIN
sales s ON s.club_id = c.idx
WHERE c.admin_id = 37
GROUP BY s.sale_event_date
ORDER BY s.sale_event_date DESC;
```

But its throwing a MySQL error - `right syntax to use near 'ON (s.rep_id != 0 AND s.qr_scanned = 1)) AS total_rep_commission, SUM(s.' at line 3`

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're doing the wrong usage of ON which should be used along with a JOIN, you could use a `CASE` in there instead.

Comment: @Prix can you please provide example

Comment: [**Sure here is a great `SELECT` example**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) and [**for `CASE` example**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your ON keyword should map with joined table

So your using wrong query

```
 ON (s.rep_id != 0 AND s.qr_scanned = 1)
```

May be it could be in WHERE condition  `(s.rep_id != 0 AND s.qr_scanned = 1)`

```
SELECT 
  c.idx, c.club_name, s.sale_event_date, s.club_id, COUNT(*) AS total_guests, 
  SUM(s.qr_scanned) AS total_scanned_guests, 
  SUM(s.rep_sale_commission) AS total_rep_commission, 
  SUM(s.sale_commission) AS total_admin_fees
FROM 
  club c 
RIGHT JOIN
  sales s 
ON 
  s.club_id = c.idx
WHERE 
  c.admin_id = 37 AND s.rep_id != 0 AND s.qr_scanned = 1 AND s.qr_scanned = 1
GROUP BY
  s.sale_event_date
ORDER BY
  s.sale_event_date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN s.rep_id != 0 AND s.qr_scanned = 1
         THEN s.rep_sale_commission 
         ELSE 0 END) AS total_rep_commission
```